# Can't capture single quote in regex

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to capture lines that look like this, for example:

```
2016/07/27 21:37:50 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process'
```

I am using the following regex pattern:

```
\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \[.*\]\[.*\] Executing Process '.*'
```

However, the line is not being captured. I noticed that it works all the way up to the single quote. But if I add the single quote, it fails. I thought there might possibly be two different types of single quotes, but I copied and pasted the quote being used, and it still didn't work. Also both quotes are being generated by the same code, so one single quote should be the same as another.

EDIT:
This the regex code.

```
regexPattern := `\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \[.*\]\[.*\] Executing Process '.*'`

log = highlight(log, regexPattern)
...
func highlight(log, pattern string) string {
    regex := regexp.MustCompile(
    matches := regex.FindAllString(log, -1)
```

Edit:
I figured it out. The log that I was getting back was HTML escaped, so the single quote was actually &#39. That prevented matching with the single quote

Comment: Please post the relevant code, as you say the strings are built dynamically.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Code that generates the log message or the regex code?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/hTE8f9, your regex matches the input string. I just copied/pasted your data. Please add the relevant details so that we could repro the issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added the code above. I do see that your example works, which is why this is confusing me.

Comment: I figured it out. The log that I was getting back was HTML escaped, so the single quote was actually &#39. That prevented matching with the single quote.

Comment: You haven't specified it in the question. So, it is still off-topic. I suggest using the regex on *plain* text, either before it is entitized, or you will have to add `(?:'|&#39;)` group to match the single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this working sample code (with `&#39`):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"
import "time"

var rgx = regexp.MustCompile(`(\d){4}\/(\d){2}\/(\d){2} (\d){2}:(\d){2}:(\d){2} (\[\w*\]){2} ([\w ])+ &#39.*&#39`)

func main() {
    s := time.Now().UTC().Format("2006/01/02 15:04:05") + ` [DEV][INFO] Executing Process &#39Some process&#39 `
    r := rgx.FindAllString(s, -1)
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

output:

```
[2016/08/11 18:13:41 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process &#39Some process&#39]
```

Try this working sample code (with `'`):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"
import "time"

var rgx = regexp.MustCompile(`(\d){4}\/(\d){2}\/(\d){2} (\d){2}:(\d){2}:(\d){2} (\[\w*\]){2} ([\w ])+ '.*'`)

func main() {
    s := time.Now().UTC().Format("2006/01/02 15:04:05") + ` [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process' `
    r := rgx.FindAllString(s, -1)
    fmt.Println(r) //

    s = `2016/07/27 21:37:50 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process'`
    r = rgx.FindAllString(s, -1)
    fmt.Println(r) // 2016/07/27 21:37:50 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process'
    fmt.Println()

    s = ` dfgfsdfg sdf gsdf gsdf 2016/07/27 21:37:50 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process' 2016/07/27 21:37:50 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process'`
    r = rgx.FindAllString(s, -1)
    fmt.Println(r) // [2016/07/27 21:37:50 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process' 2016/07/27 21:37:50 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process']
    fmt.Println()

    s = `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa asdfsf 'asdfasdf'`
    r = rgx.FindAllString(s, -1)
    fmt.Println(r) // []
}
```

output;

```
[2016/08/11 18:09:01 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process']
[2016/07/27 21:37:50 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process']

[2016/07/27 21:37:50 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process' 2016/07/27 21:37:50 [DEV][INFO] Executing Process 'Some process']

[]
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this slightly modified regex.

```
(\d){4}\/(\d){2}\/(\d){2} (\d){2}:(\d){2}:(\d){2} (\[\w*\]){2} ([\w ])+ '.*'
```

I hope it helps! If you have questions, please ask!